# How to get tweets and mentions without text?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I using twitter4j for getting tweets of some user:

```
twitter.getUserTimeline(tUser.getId(), new Paging(1, 200));
```

I want to get tweets of user without text, only date of tweet.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe the problem you are having with the code in more detail and [include a *minimal* example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

When you get a tweet, you will get all associated information about the tweet. It includes

- Tweet Text
- User name
- Created time, etc.

If you don't want text or any info, just ignore it.

In twitter4j,

```
status.getCreatedAt()
```

will give you date and time of the tweet.

Comment: I'dont need text of tweet, because their loading takes longer than the rest of the basic information.